# How to conf nginx worker_connections with cf buildpack staticfile

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, cloud-foundry

I'm using the CF buildpack *staticfile* and added the Custom Location feature to conf my Special Location (documented [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#staticfile)).

Now I want to increase the number of `worker_processes` and/or `worker_connections` used by Nginx. This is possible adding a `nginx.conf` file but this is deprecated and I would like to stick with the new pattern to only specify the conf that differs from the defaults.

Is there any way to specify `worker_connections` in a conf file that will be use when building the `nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set `worker_processes` or `work_connections` in this manner for two reasons.

1. These two properties cannot be set in a `location` block (see https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_processes and https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections).
2. The [configuration mechanism you're using will include your custom file into the single location block that is in the generated config file](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack/blob/v1.5.11/src/staticfile/finalize/data.go#L132-L134).

Thus it's not possible to set those two values using this manner, because neither can be set in a `location` block and that is the only place you can inject configuration, the `location` block using this configuration mechanism.

---

If you need to customize these settings, I would suggest that you use the nginx-buildpack instead and just provide a full custom nginx.conf file.

If you like, you can run once using the staticfile buildpack, `cf ssh` into the container, copy out the generated config file for your app, then switch to the nginx-buildpack and use the copied config file. That will give you a base configuration file, you can then edit as you need and get something similar.